# How do I use resume() in Angular JS e2e testing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I am going through step three of this angular js tutorial. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

The very last task is to "Add a `pause()` statement inside of an end-to-end test and rerun it."

I was able to add `pause()` and the test paused as it should. The question is, how to resume?

The documentation for `pause()` [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) indicates calling `resume()` in the console or clicking the resume link in the Runner UI, but I can't seem to figure out how to call resume from the console, nor can I find the resume link in the Runner UI.

How do you call `resume()`?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you put the `pause()` function call in the wrong place in your `test\e2e\scenarios.js` file.  I did this same thing - the test doesn't pause, it finishes the first or both or neither, depending on where you put the `pause()` call.

Put the `pause()` call in your `beforeEach(...)` call like so

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser().navigateTo('app/index.html');

    pause();
});
```

Then add the new `it(...)` method given in the tutorial directly after the closing parenthesis of the `it('should filter the phone...)` function.

Now the e2e test page will pause before executing each `it(...)` section and let you change the DOM contents before the test runs.  For example, if you click 'resume' without searching for anything the first test passes because there are 3 phone entries in the list.  But if you search for xyz it will fail because there will not be any phone entries in the list.

You can also place the `pause()` call before each `expect(repeater(...))` or `input('...')` call to have the test pause before each sub test.  By placing a `pause()` before each `expect(...)` call you can edit the DOM after the `input('...')` call has changed it but before the assertion is made so you can see how the input changes the content and why changing that content yourself might cause an asssertion (`expect(...)`) to fail or succeed.